# Regasm COM visible assembly on network drive using framework 4

Tags: c#-4.0, com, regasm

I've got a v4.0 library that needs to be COM visible as it will be called from a Delphi application.

Using Regasm I get the following error:

RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Development\
ENTv610\ATMSLinkClientLibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

I can get this to work if I modify the regasm.exe.config file to use:

```
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

Unfortunately I need to write an installer for this and the rest of the application. So I don't want clients to have to edit a file in their Framework folder. Is there anyway to get this library registered on a mapped drive without setting that config file?

Comment: Registering COM servers that live on remote drives is a grave mistake.  This will fail at runtime as well, for many reasons beyond security, without any decent way to diagnose the problem.  The user will just have no hope whatsoever to see that a drive mapping is no longer valid, a password is required, the network is down, etcetera.  Always make sure they are copied to a local drive.

Comment: I'm running it locally now. The reason we wanted it on a shared drive is because it's part of a main delphi application that is on that shared drive and we would have preferred a shared configuration file so we only have to change settings in one location rather than 50?